# Howto set labels match major ticks with JSlider in Java

Tags: java, swing

When I change major ticks on a JSlider, labels (if painted) don't change.

I have have this situation 
[image: first situation]

and i change major tick spacing

```
jSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(20);
```

I obtain this

[image]

how to obtain this situation ? 
[image]

Answer (score 6):

You must change labels too. Try this

```
jSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(20);       
jSlider.setLabelTable(jSlider.createStandardLabels(20));
```